# What does it mean for a sum to be majorized?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

I am working through Apostol's Introduction To Analytic Number Theory, and am struggling to understand the proof to Lemma 7.5

The proof is laid out as follows:
We begin with the sum
$$
\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n}
$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is Mangoldt's function, and express this sum in two ways. First we note that the definition of $\Lambda(n)$ gives us
$$
\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} = \mathop{\sum_{p \leq x}\sum_{a = 1}^{\infty}}_{p^a \leq x}\frac{\chi(p^a)\ln(p)}{p^a}
$$

We separate the terms with a = 1 and write
$$
\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{\chi(n)\Lambda(n)}{n} = \sum_{p \leq x}\frac{\chi(p)\ln(p)}{p} + \mathop{\sum_{p \leq x}\sum_{a = 2}^\infty}_{p^a \leq x}\frac{\chi(p^a)\ln(p)}{p^a}
$$

The second sum on the right is majorized by
$$
\sum_p\ln(p)\sum_{a = 2}^\infty\frac{1}{p^a} = ....
$$

My question is, what does it mean for a sum to be majorized, and how can I tell whether a sum is majorized or not, and if so, then by what.

Comment: "Majorized" sounds like a synonym for "bounded above."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Majorized" means "bounded above" in this context. In particular, Apostol is bounding by absolute values, and bounding each Dirichlet character trivially $\chi(p^a) \leq 1$.