# Dirichlet Character Bounding - Apostol Lemma 7.5

Tags: analytic-number-theory

This query is related to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155618/what-does-it-mean-for-a-sum-to-be-majorized), but it is on justifying the mathematics done to bound the term.

Extracting the stage of analysis that I am trying to get my head around, Apostol claims that the double sum $$\mathop {\sum\limits_{p\,\, \le \,\,x} {\sum\limits_{a = 2}^\infty  {} } }\limits_{{p^a} \le x} \,\frac{{\chi ({p^a})\log p}}{{{p^a}}}$$

can be bounded above by

$$\sum\limits_p {\log p\,} \sum\limits_{a = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{p^a}}}} $$

The one thing that disturbs me about this is the fact that the Dirichlet characters ${\chi ({p^a})}$, are, in general, complex roots of unity.

How can it be justified that summations involving complex quantities can be bounded with real numbers?

Surely the sum that generates the above analysis, $$\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le x} {\frac{{\chi (n)\Lambda (n)}}{n}} $$
will also, in general, be complex.

Apostol, in this "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" (page 151) does not make any mention of this.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help/insight.

Comment: By "bounded above", what he actually means is that
$$\left|\sum_{p \leq x} \sum_{a = 2}^{\lfloor \frac{\log x}{\log p}\rfloor} \frac{\chi(p^a) \log p}{p^a}\right| \leq \sum_p \log p \sum_{a = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^a},$$
which is clear by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply, @PeterHumphries .  Your response helps, but I still have a little unease in the back of my mind regarding the fact that a complex-valued quantity is being bounded by a real-valued quantity. Ultimately, in Apostol's analysis, he is trying to show that the term is O(1).  Is it legitimate for a complex-valued quantity so be O(1)?  Any insight most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x) = O(g(x))$ just means that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} < \infty$. There's no requirement that $f$ be real-valued and not complex-valued. You have to remember that you're bounding the *absolute value* of a complex-valued quantity by a real-valued quantity.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Aha! That is beginning to gel in my mind. Thanks so much for the time taken to address my query. Best wishes!